# Using field values from a ForeignKeyed object for ModelChoiceFields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

My friends and I play a spreadsheet-based sports picking game which is very tedious to make changes to. I've wanted to learn Django for a while so I've been working on creating it as a webapp. Here are the models I'm working with:

```
class Sheet(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
... other stuff

class Game(models.Model):
home_team = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='---')
away_team = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='---')
... other stuff

class Pick(models.Model):
sheet = models.ForeignKey(Sheet)
game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
HOME = 'H'
AWAY = 'A'
PICK_TEAM_CHOICES = (
    (HOME, 'Home'),
    (AWAY, 'Away'),
)
pick_team = models.CharField(max_length=4,
                                  choices=PICK_TEAM_CHOICES,
                                  default=HOME)
... other stuff
```

Right now, I'm trying to nail down a simple way to display the following form with information from a foreign keyed model instead of the `pick_team` default choices. The `game` is hidden because it's paired with the generated PickForm via use of the `initial` functionality in the view.

```
class PickForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = Pick
      widgets = {'game': forms.HiddenInput()}
      fields = ['sheet','game','amount','pick_type','pick_team']

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      game = kwargs['initial']['game']
      super(PickForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['pick_team']=forms.ModelChoiceField([game.away_team,game.home_team])
```

From what I can tell, the ModelChoiceField expects a queryset- so when I provide a list or a tuple, I get a `'list' object has no attribute 'iterator'` error. Knowing this now, how can I display the Game fields `home_team` and `away_team` in the pick_team dropdown on the template? Currently it defaults to 'Home' and 'Away'.

I know this is a common question at the core- how to display ForeignKeyed information in a dropdown, however all the answers I've found are fine with providing a queryset to ModelChoiceField, because they're typically trying to list a field from every object (or some filtered subset). In this case, I only want to list 2 fields, and only from one object.

I tried returning a queryset consisting of the Game object already present in kwargs, but it just displays the game's **str**() method in the dropdown, and attempting to refine the queryset with the relevant field names isn't working either.

EDIT: I realized that actually using the `home_team` and `away_team` values from the `Game` object would require extra processing on saving the `Pick`, or possibly be harder than that. Is there any way to do this sort of aliasing in the template alone? Similar to how with choice fields I can use `get_pick_team_display` to show a nicer looking display value ('Home', 'Away') instead of the vague 'H' or 'A'.

EDIT2: View code
    class GameDetail(DetailView):
    #model = Game
    template_name = 'app/games.html'
    context_object_name = 'game_detail'

```
def get_object(self):
    game = get_object_or_404(...object filtering)
    return game

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    try:
        pick = Pick.objects.get(game=context['game_detail'],
     ....other stuff)

        context['pickform'] = PickForm(initial={'game':context['game_detail'],
     .... other stuff
    except Pick.DoesNotExist:
        #pick = none
        context['pickform'] = PickForm(initial={'game':context['game_detail'],
                                            })

    return context

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = PickForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ....process form
```

Comment: Stuck in catptcha behind a slow connection. This is a quickfix approach. In your `__init__`, instead of reassigning `pick_team` field, just redefine its options as follows:

    self.fields['pick_team'].choices = (
        ('H', game.home_team),
        ('A', game.away_team),
    )

Comment: Whoa, thank you! I'm thinking in the view's post function I'll need to translate the home_team and away_team values into the generic 'home' and 'away' before saving, does that sound right?

Comment: Well, from your code posted here, you don't need to do anything else. This is just a way to sugar the user selection, while staying consistent with your model design.

Comment: Got it- as soon as I try this out successfully, I'll accept your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quickfix approach. In your `__init__`, instead of reassigning `pick_team` field, just redefine its options as follows:

```
self.fields['pick_team'].choices = (
    ('H', game.home_team),
    ('A', game.away_team),
)
```

Comment: Alright, I finally had some time to sit down and try your solution. It works perfectly for displaying the choices! But in the post method of the view, there's an issue- I have the line `form = PickForm(request.POST)` to grab the submitted form, but that instantiates a new PickForm. In the `__init__`, there are no kwargs, so retrieving the `game` errors out. There is an args array with a 'game' item, however instead of a Game object, it simply has '2'- which I think might be the object ID.

Comment: I had another idea and couldn't edit- do I need to pass the relevant `game` via `initial` as happens in `get_context_data`? I've updated my main question with view code

Comment: Alright, looks like that actually worked! I changed the line in post() to `form = PickForm(request.POST,initial={'game':Game.objects.get(id=self.request.POST['game'])})` to supply the `game`. It feels super clunky that I had to use the ID in the POST- is there a more straightforward way to do that?

Comment: Don't do that, game is hidden anyways so no use getting it from the form. In GET and in POST, get the game from the database.

Comment: I'm not really following- I didn't put any template code in, but I do display information from the `game` object there, and use `initial` to tie the `PickForm` to the `game`. Since instantiating a PickForm during post() calls `__init__`, should I pull the `game` from the database there, rather than passing through kwargs?

Comment: PickForm(request.POST,initial={'game':self.get_object()})

Comment: Oh, sorry- I knew you were referring to that, I just think I left out some relevant code that would show the game object and PickForm are tied together even in the template- so it's not as hidden as it seems, some game info is shown on the page. Are you saying it'd be better to independently get the game object from the database in GET and POST (instead of using kwargs to pass it with the form)? Apologies if I've misunderstood!